# WCF > Web Service: basicHttpBinding vs netTcpBinding

Tags: wcf, web-services, http, tcp

I'm trying to understand the basic of WCF, when I came across following question:

*Why use `basicHttpBinding` over `netTcpBinding` for a web service?*

Both of them can have a mex endpoint which allows you to add both of them easily through the *Add Server Reference* window, without any configuration at all?

I'm aware of that the `HTTP` Protocol is built on top of the `TCP` Protocol, however to me it just looks like that HTTP provides a lot of unessecary boilerplate (perfomance etc.)

Could anyone please clarify why you would choose one over the other for a web service?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has all todo with capabilities, compatability, security and performance

It boils down to: use netTcp if you're clients support WCF and are on your intranet.

use basicHtpp if you need to support 'older' (asmx) or 'compatible' (java/rails/pythone) clients, which might be on the internet.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649887.aspx

and

http://mohammedatef.wordpress.com/tag/basichttpbinding/

Comment: Thanks! - Those links were exactly what I was looking for!